# Websocket client in Erlang

Tags: erlang, client, websocket

I'd like to try to start using Erlang, and there's a data feed i'd like to read that's distributed via Websockets.  Right now i'm doing the same in node.js using the `'websocket-client`' module, but  could someone suggest a websocket client library for Erlang that I could look at?  (Or an alternative solution if I'm off the mark)

Comment: [`misultin`](https://github.com/ostinelli/misultin/blob/master/src/misultin_websocket.erl) is an erlang web server and seems to have websocket support.

Comment: @Jonas Oh I misread it. [`Here's one`](https://github.com/davebryson/erlang_websocket/blob/master/README.textile)

Comment: yaws too has something to do with web sockets. The only problem is that the implementation could be older than the newer specification on web sockets

Comment: @Muzaaya: Again, Yaws is not a **client**.

Comment: Any reason you are skipping socket.io? It will gracefully fall back on browsers that are not supporting websockets. There is also an Erlang implementation of the backend in the works.

Comment: @CRAP ANSWERS - I'm looking for a server-side client, not a server

Comment: Oh, I see. Not very often you find Erlang as a client of those things :)

Comment: I was looking for one as well, to test the websocket server implementation

Answer (score 3):

here you are: https://github.com/MiCHiLU/erlang_websocket

you may consider also gun: https://github.com/extend/gun

Answer (score 3):

Here is a promising one: https://github.com/jeremyong/websocket_client

This one didn't exist at the time the question was asked, but it's a good question that deserves to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the plug. I wrote this one so I could test my server websocket code in Erlang. The biggest things other clients were missing was wss support (https protocol), and continuation frames.

Comment: @jeremyong I was trying to use your websocket client against a cowboy websocket server but with no success. So the ws_ping_example.erl that you gave uses a `websocket_client:cast(self(), Msg)` to send a message to remote server but I cant use the same function anywhere else in the ping example code. also, is the handler only to receive messages from the remote server or can that handler also send data over websocket? Can you please throw some light ? thanks a lot.

Comment: @jeremyong Can you post a very simple example as to how we can send data to remote server. I see that you use `websocket_client:cast/2` but cant seem to use that else except the init/2 callback of the `websocket_client_handler` behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[ninenines/gun](https://github.com/ninenines/gun) seems to be the most up-to-date according to the GitHub repository page.

Here is the documentation guide on how to use it with WebSockets:
https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/gun/2.0/guide/websocket/